# how to change url before every push/replace in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

for example:

`router.beforePush = (url) => '/foo' + url`

And `history.push('/bar')` should redirect to `'/foo/bar'`

Comment: can you give more information about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy I already gave the example of what I want. And  beforePush is kind of function that I want to find